# Save file with same label with different type in python

Tags: python, scp

I have several files with the same label but the type is given by the date (e.g. example.0411, example.0406, example0324).
I want to move all the files like this from a folder to another one.
To do so, once I've done an SSH connection, I'm using the command:

```
scp.get(host_folder+'example.0411', local_folder)
```

In the folder where these files are stored, there are other folders and files which I don't want to copy.
Since I can't know which kind of date has been added as type, is there a way to copy the all the "example.something"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this command

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('find '+host_folder+' -name '+ search_message)
for line in stdout:
    
    messaggio=line.strip('\n')
    print(messaggio)
```

than I work on variable `messaggio` and recreate the path to pass via `scp.get()`
I'm 100% sure it can be done better....but I'm not an expert programmer.